How can I ouput an int value from a node tree to another object to control its rotation?
I have set up a node tree that reads the distance to a specific point in my scene and calculates the number of steps my motor needs to do to achieve such movement. My problem is for this to work I need to output the value of this calculation and read it into another object to control its rotation, possibly an armature so I can use it with marIOnette to drive my motor with it.
I have tried the output slots in the modifier and the named attribute node but I can't find a solution. I'm sure this is incredibly basic but I've been trying for days to no avail, I hope I'm not missing a tiny stupid step.
I've been googling it for a good while also, but couldn't find the answer to this specific use. Again, sorry if this is super basic.
--Edit--
Hi thanks so much for your answer! Sorry it wasn't clear. I'm not sure it's too clear in my head either. Sorry.
I'm not even sure if the result I'm getting is a float or an int, if I'm honest. I'm very new to all this. I essentially take a radius, a distance and steps per revolution, then I calculate the circumference of a circle and divide it by the number of steps in my motor giving me MMperStep, then divide the distance I want to travel by the MMperStep number giving me a steps number. All this I do using math nodes.
I would like to use this value to drive the rotation on a cube, it can be through drivers or a second node tree, so it spins based on this number in a controlled manner (ie - I can multiply the rotational value for the desired output). At the moment the number exists as you can see in the picture, it does print on the screen but I don't know how I can access it to rotate a cube that is external to this node setup.
Happy to provide the blend file if that helps. Thanks a lot in advance,

Some detail about "where" and "how" you want to use it can help finding a solution.

The solutions you mentioned should work, but we don't know what you're trying to do or how you're trying to access the properties.

Hi Daniel, thanks so much for your answer. I've edited the question for clarity. Hope that makes more sense but if not, please do let me know. Thank you so much

Many possibilities:

Create a custom group that outputs some values, Now as you modify the contents of this group, the change will propagate to all users of this group. Of course this won't work if the group is supposed to have an input. More here: Supercharge Your Geometry Nodes Workflow - Blender Tutorial

You can set the values to attributes of your geometry. Then in another object geonodes read those values:


Store

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
Read

Imgur mirror
The problem is, it is wasteful. It will be stored (duplicated) on all elements of selected domain, in the example on all vertices, curve points and point cloud points. Usually you just don't care, but if you do...

You can use a separate object to manage data, which has e.g. only one vertex.

You can also instead of having a separate object, have a separate geometry within an object, some bare vertices, which shouldn't be rendered as long as no faces are built on them. Then instead of storing data on a named attribute, you store it on their "position".



That worked really nicely and I've got a secondary geo now rotating as I expected! Thank you! Is it possible for this to affect the values in the user-facing transform (rotation) values? That would make it easier to interface with other parts of the rig for using constrains and bits like that. The ones the user can input in the object properties tab. Thanks again, amazing help.

@Victotoro I think you're after this technique: Control shape keys with drivers to the speed of rotation

I think I've got it. I'm using this solution to stablish a constrain looking at components rather than the object attributes and it is doing the job. So I have a receiver object (one vertex), that through a node tree is receiving the transformation, and then an extra object, a cube with a constrain that is looking at the vertex group I created in the receiver object. That was complex for me but it seems like it worked. Yay! Thanks all.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/323642/how-to-use-geometry-nodes-geonodes-to-rotate-an-object-so-parenting-and-constr

Ah, nice Markus, I'll take a look at that technique as well. Might better suited to my ends, idk. Thanks so much :-)
